# How to add database name to Oracle error?

Tags: oracle, oracleexception

I am copying some data via DB link from a remote DB (let's call it DB A) to another DB (DB B).

If any errors occur then I catch them and write them to a table like this:

```
EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN BEGIN
          INSERT INTO T_ERROR(...., SQLERRM, SQLCODE, ....)
        
          END;
    END;
```

So the procedure that copies data from remote DB A to DB B has been triggered and it failed, cause there was a tablespace issue on DB A.
The error logged in the table was

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_STD_TBL
```

The guys who investigated that problem believed that the problem is in DB B gave it more space still the problem persisted, then he retrieved the logs from the server, and in the log file, the error contained the DB name.

DB_A(3):ORA-1652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_STD_TBL [DB_A]

How can I get that DB-NAME and attach it to the error message?
And What is that (3)?

Comment: did you check the index tablespace for database b? it is most likely where space is run out.  check the alert.log for database b.

Comment: @scottyu we found where space has run out. It was in DB A, after space was allocated everything worked. The problem is not how to allocate space, but how to add the DB name to the error message.